# Can I run 6-3 Romex through 2ft. of 1” flexible non metalic conduit out of wall to EV charger?

Tags: gfci, conduit

Can I run 6-3 Romex through 2ft. of  1” flexible non metalic conduit out of wall to EV charger in garage? Romex will run from end of flexible conduit to 50amp breaker. Is a GFCI needed if charger is wired directly to breaker? I plan to mount EV charger less than 3ft.from breaker.

Comment: So far a GFCI is not needed for hardwire connections, only plug in.  If the garage is attached to the house, romex should be okay since it is inside.

Comment: Garage is attached. Just wanted to make sure as the flexible conduit is less than 3 feet. How many support brackets will be needed to attach conduit to wall?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the *shape* of your 6/3 NM, from what I can see. The "more rounded" type appears to JUST squeak by for 1" LFNB only if it's 24" or less (nipple fill rule allows 60%, rather than 53% for one cable.)

Which likely means the oval/flat version is too wide. I am having a lousy time getting good dimensions for those, but for an oval cable you have to treat it as a round cable of the largest dimension of the oval.

EV charger has a GFCI built-in, so if there **isn't a receptacle,** you don't need one at the breaker.

THHN/XHHW **wires** would be a lot easier if you haven't already blown money on 6/3 **cable**. Or perhaps even if you have... Those would fit (without the 24" restriction)in **3/4" LFNB**, FMC, LFMC, etc...

Or in 1/2" if under 24" long. I'd suggest 1/2" FMC (flexible metallic conduit) it's much nicer to pull in than liquid-tight. Or EMT of it's  a straight shot, assuming you don't have a bender nor want to buy one for a tiny project.

If your charger has "75°C connections" (and your breaker does, but that's pretty normal for breakers) 8 AWG copper (THHN in conduit, NOT cable, most types of which are 60°C limited) is enough for NEC (but if the manufacturer specifies larger you have to follow their directions. Not a big deal for 3 feet of wires.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Romex... but I would suggest THHN aluminum for this endeavor. 6 gauge should get the job done, and all 4 should fit in a 1" conduit.

NEC 2020 requires a GFCI breaker for *receptacles* in your garage. Hardwired chargers are not included.

Comment: And generally, the hardwired charger has a GFCI built into it.

Comment: Generally aluminum makes sense. Except that (a) some jurisdictions limit aluminum on branch circuits and more importantly, some chargers *require* copper.

Answer (score 1):

Bear with me: I got good stuff for ya.

A lot of novice EVers get into a mindset that they need a 50A circuit to charge their EV at home.  That is gross overkill for most uses. What concerns me greatly is the new 50a circuit *often overloads the panel!*   Builders don't willingly leave you 50A of headroom on a panel.

Your starting point is **a NEC Article 220 Load Calculation** to be done on the house's service. Your municipality often has a worksheet they want you to use, but many such worksheets are on the web - take one from a city, don't read commercial web sites- there's a lot of lazily written disinformation out there.

Wire cost/size (for 3 feet) is not the issue, panel loading is.  Some people say "I pinky-promise to be prudent" - that doesn't really work.

Once you know the headroom you have on your panel, the next step is getting confidence that 50A is not necessary, and Technology Connections (an avid EVer) [covers that well](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyp_X3mwE1w&t=1695s).  Now you can choose a size that is appropriate for you.  If you're V2G for 50A (or even more) that's fine IMO, the important thing is being sure.

I understand you already have a wall unit EVSE in mind, however the vast majority of those (well, not CrippleCreek) are configurable to any circuit ampacity, using DIP switches inside the EVSE, or a positively byzantine commissioning procedure using weird/special WiFi networks.  It's a UL requirement that this procedure be "hard" (DIP switch) or "hard" (difficult/byzantine).

Another option is that certain EVSEs place a "current transformer" on your service wires, reducing EV charge rate to prevent panel overload. These functionally disappear from your Load Calculation, and can be installed on a "maxed out" house.  Houses average only about 5 amps (1200W); panels are sized for peak loads and the rest of the time a house's draw is *well under* 5 amps. So that works very well.

An EVSE is [not a charger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMxB7zA-e4Y); it *is* a smart GFCI.  As such, you don't need to feed it from a GFCI breaker (because you don't need to feed a GFCI receptacle from a GFCI breaker.)

If the entire run is in conduit, you have every right to use individual wires, and I would rather see you use two #8 black copper THHN wires for hot, and one bare or green #10 for safety ground.  EVSEs do not use neutral. Really.

Not least, stranded THHN is more flexible and easier to wrestle, and conduit size won't be a factor.  Two #8 and one #10 will easily fit in 1/2" conduit.

If you must use cable, minimum conduit internal diameter is 138% of the widest width of the cable.  Spin the cable in a caliper and measure its widest point, x 1.38 and that's your minimum conduit ID.